# Trying to click a link to get a popup in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

[image]I'm trying to scrape a website, that has a link that produces a popup that I want to scrape. If I click on the product it would give me the information, but then I would have to do back() back() a million times if I get the popup I can scrape the info close the popup, and move to the next product.

[image: This is a picture of the Quick Shop link I'm trying to get]

[image: This is the picture of the popup]m/RlY2k.jpg

These are just some of the things I've tried:
quick = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.co)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.co)/div/div[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WvVG.jpg)/div[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WvVG.jpg)/div[5]/ul[2](https://i.stack.imgur.co)/li[2](https://i.stack.imgur.co)/div")
quick.click()

```
 //*[@id="js_proList"]/ul[1]/li[1]/div/div[1]/span

 //body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/ul[1]/li[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]

 //span[contains(@xpath,'1')]
```

This the code.

```
<div class="goods_img pr fast-btn-hover js_goodsHoverImg" data-goods-id="475526308" xpath="1">  <span data-logsss-const-value="" data-href="/m-goods-a-fast-id-7684901.htm" class="fast-buy js_fast_buy">QUICK SHOP</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

That Quick shop is hidden, you need to hover over it and then its interactible

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.rosegal.com/plus-size-tops-120/')
driver.maximize_window()


#get all quick shop
quick_shop_as_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='fast-buy js_fast_buy']")

#for all quick shop hover over the produc tab to display the quick shop
for i in range(0,len(quick_shop_as_list)):
    a = ActionChains(driver)
    current_product_to_hover_over = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[(@class='goods_img pr fast-btn-hover js_goodsHoverImg')]")
    a.move_to_element(current_product_to_hover_over[i]).perform()
    sleep(1)
    quick_shop_as_list[i].click()
    sleep(1)
    #there's an iframe on this pop up, have to switch to it
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_class_name('xubox_iframe')
    driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)

    #do the scrapping, im getting the whole div
    popup_div = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='page']")
    print(popup_div.text)

    #exit iframe and close the pop up
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'xubox_close')]").click()
    sleep(1)

    #will require some scroll down at some point, i think, in case that move_to_element fails
```

Comment: Thanks, art_architect. I never would have found that.